# Error docusign integration : Cannot invoke "org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject.getContent()

Tags: azure, docusignapi, bouncycastle, azure-keyvault

I am using docusign in my java microservice.
To connect to docusign, I am using a private key/value which is stored in azure vault.
I am able to get the value from the vault. When I try to convert that into bytes and send it to request a JWTUserToken from docusign,
I get an error 'Cannot invoke "org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject.getContent()" because "pemObject" is null'. Not sure what is wrong.

I see in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73206131/cannot-invoke-org-bouncycastle-util-io-pem-pemobject-getcontent-because-pem/73228083#73228083) , that we have to some this like below.

```
File inFile = new File(filePath);
Reader reader = new FileReader(inFile);
PemReader pem = new PemReader(reader);
PemObject pemObject = pem.readPemObject();
byte[] bytes = pemObject.getContent();
```

But I don't have a file, all I am reading is a string which gets converted to bytes. Not sure what's wrong in here. Any clue...

My code:
byte [] bytes = myConfigMap.getVaultSecretsMap().get("privatekey").getBytes();

```
apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code block you showed is part of our process to obtain the key bytes from a file.

If you're obtaining the bytes from a different source you could request the token with something like this:

```
 ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(configuration.getBasePath());
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(configuration.getPrivateKeyPath()));

        OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(
                configuration.getUserId(),
                configuration.getImpersonatedUserId(),
                scopes,
                privateKeyBytes,
                TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS);
        String accessToken = oAuthToken.getAccessToken();
        OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(accessToken);
        String accountId = userInfo.getAccounts().size() > 0 ?
                userInfo.getAccounts().get(0).getAccountId()
                : "";
```

See our recommended code here [Java Code](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdks/java/auth/).

Regards
Adrian
DS

Comment: thanks for the information. I am actually obtaining the bytes for a string which is a RSA private key. When I had that private key defined in my .properties file, it worked very well. When I moved that to Azure Key Vault and obtaining that string convert to Bytes array it is giving me an error. I would appreciate if could let me know how to proceed. I saw some blogs you have to use PemReader so was trying something like mentioned in my question.